# MPMoviePlayerController done button won't exit full screen

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

I have observed in iOS5, when setting the MPMoviePlayer's control style property to MPMoviePlayerControlStyleNone then entering full screen mode, the done button does not exit full screen mode. In iOS6, the done button exits full screen mode. Here is the code that I'm using, does anyone have any insight on this issue?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
    [self.playerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
    [self.playerController play];
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerController.view];
```

}

```
- (IBAction)fullScreenButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.playerController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [self.playerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if I set the control style to `MPMovieControlStyleDefault` when going to full screen, the Done button works. On `willExitFullscreen` I have to revert it back to `MPMovieControlStyleNone` and it works fine.